# Return the best factors of a whole number

Tags: vba, factors

I've just finished writing my code to return the prime factors of a number and I feel the `GetBestFactors` function could be improved.
The `GetFactors` function was hacked together from the code found here:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/202782.  This returns all the factors of a number in a collection.

The `GetBestFactors` then loops through each number finding the best set to use.
So my question is - could the `GetBestFactors` function use less `For...Next` loops?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim tmp As Collection
    Set tmp = New Collection

    Dim tmp1 As Collection
    Set tmp1 = New Collection

    Set tmp = GetFactors(15) 'Change number - will return all factors.
    Set tmp1 = GetBestFactors(15) 'Change number - will return best factors.

    Debug.Assert False

End Sub

'Returns the factors of a whole number.
Public Function GetFactors(NumToFactor As Single) As Collection

    Dim Count As Integer
    Dim Factor As Single
    Dim y As Single
    Dim tmpCollection As Collection

    Set tmpCollection = New Collection

    Count = 0
    For y = 1 To NumToFactor
        Factor = NumToFactor Mod y
        If Factor = 0 Then
            tmpCollection.Add y
        End If
    Next y

    Set GetFactors = tmpCollection

End Function

'Returns the highest factors of a number.
Public Function GetBestFactors(NumToFactor As Single) As Collection

    Dim tmpFactors As Collection
    Dim FactorNums As Collection
    Dim x As Single, y As Single, z As Single
    Dim FirstFactor As Single

    Set tmpFactors = New Collection
    Set FactorNums = New Collection

    'Get all factors for the number.
    Set FactorNums = GetFactors(NumToFactor)

    'If the collection has 1 item then the NumToFactor is 1.
    'If there's 2 items then it's a prime number (1 and NumToFactor)
    If FactorNums.Count = 1 Or FactorNums.Count = 2 Then
        tmpFactors.Add FactorNums(FactorNums.Count)
    Else
        For x = FactorNums.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
            If FactorNums(x) ^ 2 = NumToFactor Then
                tmpFactors.Add FactorNums(x)
                tmpFactors.Add FactorNums(x)
                Exit For
            Else
                For y = x To 1 Step -1
                    FirstFactor = FactorNums(y)
                    For z = y - 1 To 1 Step -1
                        If FirstFactor * FactorNums(z) = NumToFactor Then
                            tmpFactors.Add FirstFactor
                            tmpFactors.Add FactorNums(z)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next z
                    If tmpFactors.Count = 2 Then Exit For
                Next y
            End If
            If tmpFactors.Count = 2 Then Exit For
        Next x
    End If

    Set GetBestFactors = tmpFactors

End Function
```

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand the logic specifically

```
allFactors(15) = 1,3,5,15
bestFactors(15) = 3,5

allFactors(7) = 1,7
bestFactors(7) = 7

allFactors(1) = 1
bestFactors(1) = 1

allFactors(0) = empty
bestFactors(0) = empty

allFactors(-15) = empty
bestFactors(-15) = empty
```

---

All of your `Single` variables can be `Long` - single is hardly used in VBA.

Your naming could use some improvement:

```
Sub TestForFactors()

    Dim allFactors As Collection
    Set allFactors = New Collection

    Dim bestFactors As Collection
    Set bestFactors = New Collection

    Set allFactors = GetFactors(15) 'Change number - will return all factors.
    Set bestFactors = GetBestFactors(15) 'Change number - will return best factors.

    Debug.Assert False

End Sub
```

That's easier to understand.

---

[Standard VBA naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s46s4ew(v=vs.140).aspx) have `camelCase` for local variables and `PascalCase` for other variables and names. *Variable names* - give your variables meaningful names. Instead of

```
NumToFactor = numberToFactor
Count = count
Factor = factor
tmpCollection = getFactorsCollection
tmpFactors = bestFactorsCollection
FactorNums = factorNumbers
FirstFactor = firstFactor

x,y,z = ??
```

---

All of your procedures are `Public` - they should be `Private` unless needed to be `Public`.

All of your function arguments are being passed `ByRef` - they should be passed `ByVal`

---

In terms of your logic, you're looping through *every number* to find factors. There are certain rules you know you can abide by 
 - things that end with `0` or `5` 
 - no primes end in an `even` number
 - If `5` is a factor, no need to test any multiples of `5` etc

---

You're using a lot of `Collections` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579457/why-use-arrays-in-vba-when-there-are-collections you might want to try arrays or dictionaries.

---

In `GetFactors` what is `Count` doing? It's set to `0` then.. never used.

---

This is one *heck* of an arrow

```
    If FactorNums.Count = 1 Or FactorNums.Count = 2 Then
        tmpFactors.Add FactorNums(FactorNums.Count)
    Else
        For x = FactorNums.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
            If FactorNums(x) ^ 2 = NumToFactor Then
                tmpFactors.Add FactorNums(x)
                tmpFactors.Add FactorNums(x)
                Exit For
            Else
                For y = x To 1 Step -1
                    FirstFactor = FactorNums(y)
                    For z = y - 1 To 1 Step -1
                        If FirstFactor * FactorNums(z) = NumToFactor Then
                            tmpFactors.Add FirstFactor
                            tmpFactors.Add FactorNums(z)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next z
                    If tmpFactors.Count = 2 Then Exit For
                Next y
            End If
            If tmpFactors.Count = 2 Then Exit For
        Next x
    End If
```

And *a lot* of `Exit For` - there's four of those against 3 `For Next` loops - hard to follow which exits what loop.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I hadn't noticed the `Count` variable, it was  left over from the code in the link.  Again, the `Single` was left over from the code in the link - I usually use `Long` or `Double` - I think MS used `Single` to limit the numbers used as it's a slow process.  Naming conventions was me being sloppy, sorry. :)  `GetFactors` should probably be `Private` - the code was more of a stop-gap as I'd lost my way on the project I'm meant to be working on so it hasn't a specific use yet.  I think naming is one of the hardest parts when coding - allfactors and bestfactors are better

Comment: I did consider using a `Dictionary`, but I've only just started getting my head around them so stuck with what I knew - I should rewrite though.  The `For...Next` loops was the main bit I was thinking about - it didn't feel right adding all those `Exit For`s but I needed a way to exit all the way out of the loops once the inner loop had populated the collection.  I'll have another look at the way the logic works - makes sense with the not ending with an even number.  I'm not sure what you mean by logic at the top of your post - sorry, didn't mention it's for positive numbers only.

Comment: The "BestFactors(7)" doesn't return `1`

Comment: Ah, right.  1 will only ever return 1 as the result, a prime number will only ever return 1 and itself.  My line of thinking was that I'd want to figure out which numbers I need to multiply to get the originally entered number and if it's a prime number then the 1 would be superfluous to the equation so I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the response from Raystafarian I've rewritten the code using the Dictionary object in `AllFactors` (previously `GetFactors`) - this returns an array rather than a collection which is faster to reference.
I've also removed all the looping in `BestFactors` (previously `GetBestFactors`).
After listing all the factors for 1000 numbers it was obvious that matching factors run in order - so I just had to take the correct paring.

e.g:
*The factors for 12* are: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 & 12.
Ignoring 1 & 12 (the first set), I take 2 & 12.

*The factors for 990* are: 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 15, 18, 22, 30, 33, 45, 55, 66, 90, 99, 110, 165, 198, 330, 495 and 990.
Ignoring 1 & 990, I take 2 and 495.

I'm not sure how much this has improved the code - but not having to loop through the factors must be a huge saving, which I'll test at some point with a really high number.

```
Sub Test()

'   Return all factors from 1 to 1000 in columns on Sheet1.
'
'    Dim tmp() As Variant
'    Dim x As Long, y As Long
'
'    For x = 1 To 1000
'        tmp = AllFactors(x)
'        For y = 0 To UBound(tmp)
'            Sheet1.Cells(y + 1, x) = tmp(y)
'        Next y
'    Next x

    Dim tmp1 As Variant, tmp2 As Variant
    Dim tmp3 As Variant
    tmp1 = BestFactors(12) 'Returns 2 & 6.
    tmp2 = BestFactors(990) 'Returns 2 & 495.
    tmp3 = BestFactors(9) 'Returns 3 & 3.

    Debug.Assert False

End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose   : Returns the factors of a whole positive number.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function AllFactors(NumToFactor As Long) As Variant

    Dim lngFactor As Long
    Dim lngNumeric As Long
    Dim dict As Object

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For lngNumeric = 1 To NumToFactor
        lngFactor = NumToFactor Mod lngNumeric
        If lngFactor = 0 Then
            'No need to check if it exists -
            'each value only appears once.
            dict.Add lngNumeric, lngNumeric
        End If
    Next lngNumeric

    AllFactors = dict.items()

End Function

Public Function BestFactors(NumToFactor As Long) As Variant

    Dim vAllFactors() As Variant

    vAllFactors = AllFactors(NumToFactor)

    Select Case UBound(vAllFactors)
        Case 0, 1
            'Prime number or 1.
            BestFactors = vAllFactors
        Case Is >= 2
             BestFactors = Array(vAllFactors(UBound(vAllFactors) - 1), _
                            vAllFactors(LBound(vAllFactors) + 1))
    End Select

End Function
```

**Edit**:  I've changed the last line of code as realised it was silly - `vAllFactors(UBound(vAllFactors) - (UBound(vAllFactors) - 1))` to get the second lowest value... use `vAllFactors(LBound(vAllFactors) + 1)`